# 3D object location to 2D image

Tags: c++, math, matrix, graphics, 3d

I am using ROS to record data from CARLA Simulator. I want to render a bounding box on the RGB Front camera image that correspond to the other vehicle's location.

Here is an example frame from the bag file:
[image]

Let's say my ego vehicle's position is (60, -65, 0.7) and the red vehicle's position is (45, -70, 0.8) in the current image, and the scale is (4, 2, 1). I came up with the following code based on my understanding of graphics math, but I do not know the focal length or the principal point for CARLA's camera.

```
// Camera intrinsic parameters (calibration)
double focal_length_x = ...;
double focal_length_y = ...;
double principal_point_x = ...;
double principal_point_y = ...;

// Vehicle's world position
Vector3d vehicle_position_world(45, -70, 0.8);

// Camera's world position
Vector3d camera_position_world(60, -65, 0.7);

// Calculate the relative position of the vehicle to the camera
Vector3d relative_position = vehicle_position_world - camera_position_world;

// Calculate 2D camera coordinates using the projection formula
double camera_x = (relative_position.x() / relative_position.z()) * focal_length_x + principal_point_x;
double camera_y = (relative_position.y() / relative_position.z()) * focal_length_y + principal_point_y;
```

Could someone please help me with the correct way to convert and get an accurate location of the bounding box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First: we have no info about your coordinates systems and units and cameras you refer to so its impossible to answer in specific therms... You should add image describing those and also camera info like FOV per each axis, camera resolution, chips sensor dimensions...

If you know `FOVx,FOVy` of your camera then along with its resolution `xs,ys` you can compute focal length so you can cast 3D ray per any screen 2D position

```
FOVx = 2*tan(xs/(2*focal_length))
FOVy = 2*tan(ys/(2*focal_length))

focal_length = xs/(2*atan(FOVx/2))
focal_length = ys/(2*atan(FOVy/2))
```

If you have also depth info you can compute the 3D position relative to camera for each pixels.

If you don't you can assume road is "flat ground" if you know your camera position relative to ground you can compute distance for each road pixel (3D position) so just find pixel of your target that neighbors road pixels and you have your relative (to camera) 3D position ...

so if yo have just RGB then:

1. create ROI of road pixels neighboring your target (object of interest)
2. for each its pixel cast 3D ray from camera focal point to 2D position on the chip sensor
3. compute intersection between ray and ground

   the result is your 3D position ...

beware this will be way of for non flat roads (curved slopes up/down hill)

If you need more 3D info then you can also cast rays from ground in straight up direction so you can compute 3D info of some pixels above ground.

For non ground related stuff you have to find ethalones (objects of known physical size like road signs...) compute its visual size, compute scale from it and then use that to compute distance after that you can compute 3D position of it and its neighboring pixels ...